# Store every line of a file as string in array

Tags: c

I have a file that looks like this:

```
Tom
John
Sarah
...
```

I need to read this file and store each name in an array. The number of lines is unknown and can vary. The new line character would be `\n` I assume (of course that is not visible in the file).

I have to use the open function providing my own buffering.

This is what I have so far:

```
#define BUFFSIZE        4096

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
        int n;
        char buf[BUFFSIZE];

        // Throw error if not exactly 2 arguments
        if(argc != 2) {
                printf("Usage: %s <file_name>\n", argv[0]);
                exit(-1);
        }

        // open file and check if error thrown
        int readFileDescriptor = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
        if (readFileDescriptor == -1) {
                printf("Error with file open\n");
                exit (-1);
        }

        // Read until end of file was reached
        while((n = read(readFileDescriptor, buf, BUFFSIZE)) > 0) {
                // ... do something here
        }
        if(n < 0) {
                printf("Read error\n");
        }

        close(readFileDescriptor);
        return(0);
}
```

Firstly, I am not sure how to overcome the problem if a name is cut off in the middle due to the buffer. Secondly, how do I split by the `/n` character and put each name into the array. For the array I was told to use a dynamic array with malloc and realloc in order to change sizes of it.

Thanks a lot in advance! I am stuck with this for a while already and don't know where to continue anymore.

Comment: Look at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html

Comment: Well, `char buf[BUFFSIZE]` is not a dynamic buffer so you should start by using malloc to allocate a buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following algorithm:

1. Fill the buffer.
2. Check the buffer for the first newline character.
3. If there is no newline character, stop, you are done.
4. Allocate a new buffer the size of the entry whose end you just found.
5. Copy the entry whose end you found in step 2 into the budffer.
6. Move any characters left in the buffer to the beginning of the buffer.
7. Go to step 1.

This is not spectacularly efficient, but it will get the job done.

Comment: Thanks for your input!!

Answer (score 0):

Possible alternatives:

a) When you remove anything from the buffer (e.g. from the start of the buffer to the middle), shift any remaining data (e.g. shift the data from the middle to the end back to the start) and then fill the buffer again (from the new middle to the end). Note: This can't work if one line of text can be larger than the buffer.

b1) Make the buffer larger than the file. That way you can just replace newline characters with string terminators (and maybe discard any "end of line white space" and skip empty lines, etc); and avoid a whole pile of "`malloc()` overhead" because you don't need to allocate memory for each individual string (because you're re-using the memory you already allocated). Note: This can't work if the file can be larger than available virtual memory.

b2) Use `mmap()` to memory map the file; then replace newline characters with string terminators, etc. Note: This can't work if the file can be larger than available virtual memory.

c1) Stop using awful "plain text" file formats and just store strings (with string terminators and without any newline characters) in the file to start with. This allows you to `mmap()` without modifying the memory after. Note: This can't work if the file can be larger than available virtual memory.

c2) Stop using awful "plain text" file formats, store strings in the file, but also have a list/array/index of "offset in the file for start of string" at the start of the file. This allows you to `mmap()` without modifying the memory, and also avoids the need to scan through the entire file searching for the end of each string/start of the next string. Note: This can't work if the file can be larger than available virtual memory.

If the file's data is already cached in RAM by the operating system; "option c2)" might be 1000 times faster than "option a)".

e) Combine "option b2)" with "option c2)". When your program starts compare the time stamps for "input.txt" and "input.bin" and if "input.txt" is newer use "option b2)", generate an index, and save it as "input.bin" for next time; otherwise (if "input.bin" is newer) use "option c2)".